# Laravel 5.6 CSRF token not validating / checked

Tags: laravel-5, csrf, laravel-5.6, csrf-protection

I have:

**Blade**

```
<form class="form-horizontal was-validated" method="POST" action="{{ route('account.applications.index')}}">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  {{-- yadda yadda yadda --}}
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">&nbsp;</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input id="application_type" type="hidden" name="application_type" value="{{ Request::get('application') }}">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

received by controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $requestData = $request->all();

    $requestData['application_id'] = strtolower(trim($requestData['application_id'].'.'.config('app.fqdn_base')));

    $request->replace($requestData);

    $values =  $this->validate($request, [
        'application_type' => 'required|exists:applications,name',
        /* other validations */
    ]);

    $exitCode = Artisan::call('tenant:create', [
        /* passing param here */
    ]);

    $host = Hostname::where('fqdn', $values["application_id"])->first();
    $web = $host->website;

    $web->name = $values["application_name"];
    $web->application_id = Application::where('name', '=', $values["application_type"])->pluck('id')->first();
    $web->owner = auth()->id();
    $web->save();

    $applications = Application::where('id', '!=', '0')->get();
    return view('admin.applications', [ "applications" =>  $applications]);
}
```

above code is working fine, except... CSRF function, I have check that I could retrieve CSRF value from request.

however, once my transaction done and redirect to the page that I want, If I press F5 it will re-submit the form, and this should result CSRF missmatch, but in my case, It didn't.

is there a specific way to turn on CSRF validation?

Comment: Can you post HTTP request for above request/function?

Comment: Please also make sure that you have not excluded above URL from CSRF protection. Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

Comment: @SavanGadhiya, no, there isn't excluding. and i can see the _token was submitted on request param: `+request: ParameterBag {#43 ▼
    #parameters: array:6 [▼
      "_token" => "LI3A2K6NQiTYnBHJBNGMgV2bs7equWW8TnGZ999"
      "application_id" => "asdasdasm"
      "application_name" => "1asdas"
      "password" => "asdfasdf"
      "password_confirmation" => "asdfasdf"
      "application_type" => "emm"
    ]
  }`

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but I believe your CSRF check is working fine.

As I understand it, the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware used in Laravel simply indicates whether the the XSRF-TOKEN should be set on the response, and the `{{ csrf_field() }}` is a helper function that gets the `$session->token()`. Since you're hitting F5 to re-submit the form, I believe the `{{ csrf_field() }}` is now pointing at your new session token cookie, and passes the check.

You're not submitting the form via AJAX/Axios so Laravel should be handling the entire request, part of which includes verifying the CSRF Token from your current session, as opposed to verifying a saved/serialized version of your CSRF Token from the previous session.